# How is the best way to create a login for both a user and an admin in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking to create diverts to an admin area where the type column in the users table has a value of A. Else they get diverted to a users area.

I have however seemed to have found a number of different ways ways from guards to re-directs and middleware groups. How you recommend and implement such logins?

Comment: You'd better use the user roles/permissions system that comes with L5.2, then u can use middleware to prevent non-admin users from accessing the admin routes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your tables are setup. The easiest and most common way is to have a column on your users table that represents if the user is and admin (such as is_admin).

If you want them to go separate places after login the best solution would be to override the login function of the original AuthController (just make a new postLogin) and redirect based on the field is_admin.

Something like

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    // setup rules for validation of user input
    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];

    // run validation, if this does not pass Laravel will redirect back with input and errors
    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    // attempt to authenticate the user
    if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')]))
    {
        here you should check the user which just happens to be stored in Auth::user()
    }
    else
    {
        // the attempt was not correct, lets redirect back with input and an error
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['The user information is invalid']);
    }
}
```

You would need to create some middleware to ensure that the users accessing the route is an admin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column Named position in members or user table and store a value admin which username and password are using for login as admin.

when form is submitted then check if position is equal to admin then redirect on admin page else redirect on user page,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set up authorization with sentinel. It providers you user creation with roles, you can add roles too.
All you have to do is add the package to your composer file, composer update and publish the vendor with artisan.
Here is how you can achieve that, [sentinel setup.](http://www.sitepoint.com/removing-the-pain-of-user-authorization-with-sentinel/) It provides you permissions but in your case you would group your middleware.
All you have to do is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\SentinelAdmin'], function()
{
//Your admin routes
});
```

Define your routes that you want only the admin to access inside that function. Similarly you can define user routes inside the user middleware.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\SentinelUser'], function()
{
// Your user routes
}
```

These are provided for you from the package. You can create more roles and your own middleware respectively.
You have a shorthand representation of the middleware once it is defined in the service provider but I used the full path for your better understanding.